# How can I pass email with a + as asp.net web Api parameter

Tags: asp.net, rest, web

How can I pass "name+first@domain.com" as a parameter to the asp.net web api method? plus sign automatically get replaced with space ("name first@domain.com")

ASP.net 4.5

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about rest, but can't you replace the '+' with a ' ' by using `string.Replace` before adding it as parameter or after retrieving it from the parameters?

Comment: Thanks, But hope there is better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("name+first@domain.com")` before you call the method.
And `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to decode the string if necessary.

**Update**
To call the web api method from javascript and escape the +, then you can use: `encodeURIComponent("name+first@domain.com")`

To decode use `System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(escapedParameter);`

Comment: Thanks. encodeURIComponent("name+first@domain.com") did work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

Change in the URI for your method of your api.

```
[Route("RegisterUser?email={email}")]
```

Now change the url of the method accordingly.
new URL for calling the mehod will be `http://api/name_Controler/RegisterUser?email=escape('name+first@domain.com')`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you are encoding the URL right? I had a similar situation and this issue is intermittent. Any other character can be dealt with using HttpUtility.UrlEncode("!&*~*^((");

But + (plus) doesn't fit there, and as I said it happens sometimes. So I decided to switch to GetQueryNameValuePairs

```
var queryParams = this.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToList();
var userId = queryParams.Single(q => q.Key.ToLower() == "userid").Value;
var password = queryParams.Single(q => q.Key.ToLower() == "password").Value;
```

You still have to encode though